# Why is ParDo not working on DataflowRunner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, psycopg2, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm having a problem when I **switch from the DirectRunner to Dataflowrunner**:  Pardo apparently does not work.  When I set runner to Dataflowrunner, **def process(self, query)** never runs.
I can see the job working on GCP, however, my method InsertPostgresql doesn't work using Dataflowrunner.

According to the log error, apparently ParDo is not recognizing the 'psycopg2'.

> process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined During handling of
> the above exception

[image: psycopg2' is not defined]

I wonder why ?

```
def run_pipeline(): 
      
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'C:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\<mycredentialfile>.json'
     
        optionsGCP = {
            'streaming': True,
            'project':"<myproject>",
            'region':"us-central1",
            'temp_location':"gs://poc360-bucket/temp",
            'staging_location':"gs://poc360-bucket/staging",
            'drivername':"postgresql",
            'save_main_session': True,
            'setup_file': r'C:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\setup.py'     
        }
    
        paramsDB = {
            'database': '<mydatabase>',
            'user': '<myuser>',
            'password': '<mypassword>',
            'host': 'localhost',
            'port': '5000'
        }
    
        class InsertPostgresql(beam.DoFn):
    
            def __init__(self, **server_config):
                self.config = server_config
    
            def process(self, query):
                con = psycopg2.connect(**self.config)
    
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute(query)
                con.commit()
                resultado=cur.fetchall() 
                cur.close()
                con.close()
                
                yield resultado
    
        runner='Dataflowrunner' 
        options = PipelineOptions(**optionsGCP)
        options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
        options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True 
    
        sql="select public.Insert_tbCadastro('01','010',431,'A',501741,000000,'2020-10-26','A')"
     
            
        p = beam.Pipeline(runner=runner,options=options)
        data = (p
            | beam.Create([sql]) 
            | beam.ParDo(InsertPostgresql(**paramsDB)) 
        )
        
        data | 'teste' >> beam.Map(print)
        print("Lines: ", data)
    
        result = p.run()
        result.wait_until_finish()
    
    if __name__=='__main__':
        run_pipeline()
```

Leaving the job executing, I got, after some time, this:

```
2020-11-12T11:54:12.718405344ZError message from worker: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -134644: Traceback (most recent call last): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1344, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "c:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\PipelinePoc360.py", line 45, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 256, in _execute response = task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 313, in <lambda> lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 482, in do_instruction return getattr(self, request_type)( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 518, in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 982, in process_bundle input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 219, in process_encoded self.output(decoded_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 330, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 332, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1279, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1371, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1279, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1371, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1294, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 446, in raise_with_traceback raise exc.with_traceback(traceback) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1344, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "c:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\PipelinePoc360.py", line 45, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-134636'] java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.finish(RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.java:333) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:85) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1365) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:154) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1085) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -134644: Traceback (most recent call last): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1344, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "c:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\PipelinePoc360.py", line 45, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 256, in _execute response = task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 313, in <lambda> lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 482, in do_instruction return getattr(self, request_type)( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 518, in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 982, in process_bundle input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 219, in process_encoded self.output(decoded_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 330, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 332, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1279, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1371, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1279, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1371, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1294, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 446, in raise_with_traceback raise exc.with_traceback(traceback) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1344, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "c:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\PipelinePoc360.py", line 45, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-134636'] org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.FnApiControlClient$ResponseStreamObserver.onNext(FnApiControlClient.java:177) org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.FnApiControlClient$ResponseStreamObserver.onNext(FnApiControlClient.java:157) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onMessage(ServerCalls.java:251) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:33) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onMessage(Contexts.java:76) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailableInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:309) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailable(ServerCallImpl.java:292) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:782) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Besides everything above, the job accuses :

[image: timeout]

**After aplying a setup.py file, i got:**

[image: warning]

setup.py:

```
import setuptools 

setuptools.setup(
    name='psycopg2',
    version='2.8.6',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

**Dataflow Log error:**

```
2020-11-12T21:11:50.946327861ZError message from worker: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error 
received from SDK harness for instruction -1396: Traceback (most recent call last): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in
 apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1344, in 
apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "c:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\PipelinePoc360.py", line 48, in process
 NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback
 (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 256, 
in _execute response = task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 313, 
in <lambda> lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 482, in do_instruction return 
getattr(self, request_type)( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 518, 
in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 982, in process_bundle
 input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded( 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 219, in process_encoded self.output(decoded_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 330, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 332, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670,
 in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, 
in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1215, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1279, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1371, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", 
line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", 
line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, 
in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1215, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1279, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1371, 
in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", 
line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", 
line 670, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", 
line 671, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1215, 
in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1294, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", 
line 446, in raise_with_traceback raise exc.with_traceback(traceback) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1344, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File "c:\Users\julianocm\Desktop\POC\PipelinePoc360.py", 
line 48, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-1388'] 
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) 
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57) 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.finish(RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.java:333) 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:85) 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123) 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1365) 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:154) 
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1085) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -1396: 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py",
```

**Using requirements.txt:**

[image: execution]

I'm still waiting for the job log... until now, my PostgreSQL table still empty.

After a few minutes I got the log, I'm still unable to define psycopg2:

```
line 48, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-208'] org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.FnApiControlClient$ResponseStreamObserver.onNext(FnApiControlClient.java:177) org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.FnApiControlClient$ResponseStreamObserver.onNext(FnApiControlClient.java:157) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onMessage(ServerCalls.java:251) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:33) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onMessage(Contexts.java:76) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailableInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:309) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailable(ServerCallImpl.java:292) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:782) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My requirements.txt:

[image: file]

**After the troubleshooting guide regarding to [NameErros](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors)**

Apparently, We fixed the NameError. Now I'm trying to figure out why I don't have my SQL executed. My job still working, but my PostgreSQL does't have any record. So, something still wrong.

[image: Job]

When I debug, the lines in "process" are ignored. Are the arguments being used correctly?

[image]

And after all:

[image: timeout]

Thank you,
Juliano

Comment: In the Dataflow UI in the Developer Console, do you see any data being processed by the steps in your pipeline? Are there any errors visible there?

Comment: I'm assuming InserePostgresql vs InsertPostgresql is a typo while creating this SO question?

Comment: Morning.
@PeterKim I just translated the name of the method. Pardo is calling "InsertPostgresql", but it is not running the SQL script. When I run on DirectRunner, it inserts the record properly and the stored procedure returns a number reporting that the insertion has happened.

Comment: @danielm I just checked out that the job now audit an error. I  just updated my post

Comment: Looks like ParDo is not recognizing the 'psycopg2':

" process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined During handling of
 the above exception "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be related with global imports. As can be seen in this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors) it is a common issue when switching from direct runner to dataflow runner which matches your actual case.

Given that you already tried the solution of adding the flag `--save_main_session=True`, I would try importing the module in the function itself, meaning instead of:

```py
import psycopg2
(...)
def process(self, query):
  con = psycopg2.connect(**self.config)
```

try:

```py
def process(self, query):
  import psycopg2
  con = psycopg2.connect(**self.config)
```

---
**Edit**

Given that we bypassed that error and it works properly in DirectRunner I doubt the issue is found in the code itself. I would look at the firewall rules to ensure Dataflow workers can connect to the PostgreSQL db and I would check that the controller service account has the necessary permissions.

I see that you specify some credentials within your code, take into consideration that the Dataflow workers use the default [controller service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#controller_service_account) `<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` or a custom one and they need to have the necessary permissions to connect to the database.

Both things (Firewall rules/Service account used by the workers) are potential differences between direct runner and dataflow runner and thus could be the cause of the issue, review them.

Comment: Morning @aemon4, thank you 

Now I don't have any errors , however, I don't have my data into postgresql table.  until now, i don't have any log available.. so i don't know what's happening...  
I just updated my post with an image of my dataflow UI. 

What should I do ? Thank you

Comment: I don't know why, but running on dataflow the method : def process(self, query) is never executed, when i debug, the compiler jump the process, all lines are ignored of it. =(
Running on directrunner, works perfectly.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide some leads of where I think the error could be. Review them and let us know if they help or you still are stuck.

Comment: Thank you @aemon4, I'm going to check it out now. The link you have provided: controller service account is not working.. could you send it to me? Thank you

Comment: My bad, I inserted the same link as before. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you @aemon4
I'm still trying here.. reviewing all permissions ... until now.. i'm still with no data into Posgresql DB. at least, my job doesn't have any error... but.. the main problem persists...

Comment: Morning
I'm still struggling here... I'm reviewing all settings of my GCP... til now, looks like all fine.. not sure what else to check out.
my "        def process(self, element):" still not executing on dataflowrunner .

I tried to execute the wordcount sample on dataflowrunner, it has the same problem.. 

='(

Comment: I’ve tried to run the wordcount example with DataflowRunner in [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#run-wordcount-on-the-dataflow-service) and I could do it without any issues, the outputs were properly written in GCS. By experiencing the same issue you mean no records were written in GCS? Or in PostgreSQL after modifying the code? Check if following the exact tutorial records are written in GCS or not. Also look for warnings/Errors in the dataflow step logs (In Logging) in case there are any clues there.

Comment: Hi, I tried again and wordcount ran correctly. 

Back to my program, I found out one warning that says : 
2020-11-15T19:06:50.571008791ZWorkflow config is missing a default resource spec.

What does it mean ? 

Thank you

Comment: I am not entirely certain what is the root cause of that warning message but I have seen it in the past for a wide variety of reasons. I doubt we will be able to find the root cause with that message alone. 
Feel free to include all the warning/error messages you can find in order to help you troubleshoot the issue but for better debugging I would recommend contacting Google Cloud Support as they should be able to help you troubleshoot your issue further and faster.

Comment: Thank you @aemon4, I just re-wrote everything and now it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the psycopg2 package isn't being provided to the worker.  See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/ for information about how to manage dependencies in python.  In this case, since psycopg2 is available in PyPi, you just need to include it in a requirements.txt file that you pass via the --requirements_file pipeline option.

Comment: Thanks @denielm, I'm trying to use it. 
I'm waiting for Dataflow to log something.

Comment: I just got the dataflow log. I still have the problem. I just updated the SO question. 
Not working yet :(

Comment: What you did named your your code as a package psycopg2; it didn't add that as a dependency.  Since your code is in all in a single file, the requirements.txt method will be the easiest way to get this working

Comment: Hi @danielm
I'm using now the requirements.txt, I'm waiting for something to happen...because it still running.... the job is not available on dataflow UI yet...
I updated the SO question with an image of my gloud shell.
thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same problem:

line 48, in process NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-208'] 

Am I doing something wrong ?